# Tell me the "right way" to build objects from JSON

Tags: coffeescript

Say I have a class, for example:

```
class myClass
   name: ""
   id: ""
```

And say I have some JSON like:

```
[{name:"foo", id:1}, {name:"bar", id:2}]
```

Tell me a generic way to build an array of myClass objects from the array above (without manually mapping each field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring):

```
class MyClass
  constructor: ({@name, @id}) ->

instances = (new MyClass o for o in objs)
```